# How can i get text from website and refresh that check every second?

Tags: python, text, python-2.7

what should i use to get the text from Website... 
exactly from the small area 20x20 pix
example: Get text from area, value of that text put in to event with action like click when the text is ASD

I just learned how to use GetPixelColor, ImageGrab, but sadly i can't find the most important: Text Grab
Is there an option to use something very similar to ImageGrab?

```
def screenGrab():
box = (347,170,1130,713)
im = ImageGrab.grab(box)
im.save(os.getcwd() + '\\full_snap__' + str(int(time.time())) +
'.png', 'PNG')
```

I am sorry for my English and for maybe a newbie question, but i am just starting with Python.

Comment: if text is x,give back y??

Comment: Ask site owners for the API that will provide you with this very info. That's the only way.

Comment: It's okay to be a beginner, but if you want people to help you here then show us your work so far. What you've tried (but failed), what ideas you have in mind and so on. And then, we will be more than happy to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to do for a specific pixel area, but you could get the HTTP response body (e.g. the HTML of the web page you want) by making an HTTP request to the website and reading the response. You can do that with Python's httplib package. Then parse the response, e.g. using an XML package such as Python's xml.dom.minidom. Find the XML element containing the text you want in the DOM and then act appropriately.

Comment: Thank you! I will try XML Package for that, becouse the area of text what i want to Get is in Element, so it should be easier.